# HapiJS returns 400 error on Delete

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, hapi.js

I am getting a "statusCode": 400 when sending a delete request. On my `delete.route.js` I have this:

```
async handler(req) {
  const { portfolioId } = req.params

  const deletePortfolio = await service.deletePortfolio(portfolioId)

  return deletePortfolio
},
```

In my service which I have this. This works the same as creating but I haven't deleted anything with mongodb and hapi yet.

```
async deletePortfolio(portfolioId) {
    const deletePortfolio = await this.model.findOneAndDelete({
      _id: portfolioId,
    })
    return deletePortfolio
}
```

You can see the full code in context here:

https://github.com/imcodingideas/crypto-portfolio/blob/master/server/src/portfolio/delete.route.js

Comment: Don't await a value inside a function to then return it. It actually ends up as a no-op since it will simply return the Promise anyway. Simply return the promise as you should have also noticed that you need to do this anyway as you have `await service.deletePortfolio(..)`. Note that `.findOneAndDelete()` is returning the document from "before" deletion with these options, but none of this should have anything to do with the 404. In fact a 404 should not be related to any of this code at all as it's simply a "not found". More likely a wrong url unless you can confirm this code executes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the server response for your request? I believe it can be related to your validation rule.

```
validate: {
          params: {
            portfolioId: Joi.string().required(),
          }
        }
```

Are you sure your portfolioId is a string? I've checked your client code but couldn't spot your delete request point.